# BeanUtils.copy not work - Error not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I make a very little Spring boot app in which I'm doing practice as to how use BeanUtils.copy. I wonder, although I do everything fine from my side but error persist.

App works fine If I just go with Entity table & getting data directly UserEntity through @RequestBody & parse to repository, but when I try to map data from DTO table to UserEntity it gives me an error :

```
      "not-null property references a null or transient value"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Controller

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails){
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(userEntity, userDetails);
    userRepository.save(userEntity);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Created");
  }
```

UserRespository

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
}

public class UserEntity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String userId;

@Column(nullable=false, length=50)
private String firstName;

@Column(nullable=false, length=50)
private String lastName;

@Column(nullable=false, length=120)
private String email;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String encryptedPassword;
```

}

```
public class UserDetailsRequestModel(DTO) {
  private String userId;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String email;
  private String encryptedPassword;
}
```

Data I'm sending from PostMan,

```
 {
   "userId": "12",
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "email": "John@doe.com",
   "encryptedPassword": "123"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the mistake was not using BeanUtils right way.
I used before:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(userEntity, userDetails);
```

Right way is:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetails, userEntity);
```

In fact, destination table where data being thrown should be kept at 2nd place.